# JavaScript linking two objects

Tags: javascript

What is a memory efficient way to link two objects?  If you store objects using two arrays with corresponding index values the object won't be released from memory.

The implementation should look like the following.

```
var obj ={};
var linkedobj = getLinkedObject(obj);
var obj2 ={}
var linkedobj2 = getLinkedObject(obj2);
```

Comment: Memory efficient in what sense? In terms of releasing the memory to the GC? If so that depends on how you clean up.  Or memory efficient in terms of memory used - in which case it's hard to see how this relates to linking the objects.  Can you clarify your goal?  In you example implementation obj2 is never used - is that intentional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Objects are general containers**

If all you want to do is associate one object with another one, then why not have them point to one another?

```
var obj = {};
var obj2 = {};

obj.linkedObject = obj2;
obj2.linkedObject = obj;
```

This would a normal thing to do, and doesn't have bad implications on memory.

**Releasing memory**

If you are asking about holding a table full of object references, you are correct that the object will not disappear until all of the live references to it are gone. Javascript has a garbage collector, and as long as your table or array has a good reference, it will be backed by memory for you. If you give an object to a table and then want it to be deleted from memory entirely, you can simply remove it from your table also. You could also just remove the table, assuming it doesn't need to hold anything else.

If you are determined to have a `getLinkedObject` function return an object for another object, you can still allow the objects to each hold the associate reference.

```
function getLinkedObject(anObject) {
    return anObject.linkedObject;
}
```

This would probably be accompanied by a counterpart:

```
function linkObjects(anObject, anotherObject) {
    anObject.linkedObject = anotherObject;
    anotherObject.linkedObject = anObject;
}
```

Doing this allows you to worry a little less about memory management, which in Javascript (a high-level, dynamic environment with a garbage collector) is typically appropriate.

Comment: Yeah initially I would do that except I'm attempting to link Array.prototype to an object and I don't really want to add proper ties to Array.prototype

Comment: Also appropriate with today's PCs is don't worry about memory at all.  How many objects would you need to create in JavaScript to equate to one high resolution png on your page?  Assuming of course you aren't just looping and leaking objects - in which case the problem runs deeper.

Comment: @James- That's practically true. But of course it's good to explore the question for the sake of understanding.

Comment: @Lime- You can always just access Array.prototype by name, if that helps with your specific code problem.

Comment: @keparo could you explain a little bit more.  Do you mean `Array.name` because that isn't cross browser (some IE versions) or something else.

Comment: @Lime- A getter function could return a reference to Array.prototype (literally `return Array.prototype`) or any object living on Array.prototype (`return Array.prototype.slice`) without a problem.

Comment: Thanks, I've concluded there isn't a way.  Well not yet.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you use keparo's answer, which from your follow-up comment sounds like not an option, what you're asking for is basically impossible. Because, since you can't augment the original object, you need some method of storing a reference to it. But (since JavaScript has no concept of weak references) this will always prevent it from being garbage collected, contradicting your requirements statement.

Comment: Originally I was attempting to do this client side.  But it would be beneficial if a feature like this was implemented in node.js

Comment: It'd have to be implemented in the language, not the server-sided framework.

Comment: Considering you can write c/c++ plugins/modules I'm assuming there is some way to get store the memory address of the Objects or at least save a soft reference to an Object.  I would have to get more involved with the v8 engine and node.js to be certain though.